# Receive messages from Messenger group chat using Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger

I'm trying to implement a bot chat in a facebook account (Not in a facebook fanpage). I don't know how to check if someone send me a message so I can response. There are a Python lib used to support this feature called fbchat but it's not supported this feature anymore. Is there anyway i can resolve this problem ? I tried using selenium to login and find exact a specific conversation    automatically, but i still haven't figured out how to solve the problem yet. Thank you for reading

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Facebook does not have any API for it. And Facebook does not allow you to do anything else than using their API. So no it is not possible.

Comment: So strict :( Thank you for your answer >m<